# Passing data using HTML tags and innerHTML, setAttribute(), etc. Editing and updating news articles stored in a database

Tags: javascript, input, parameters, tags, innerhtml

I have a simple news update interface where I read news headlines/titles from a database and print them on page as a list. The goal is, that when I click one of the headlines it brings out an area with a form where the news article could be modified and then updated back into database.

Now in order to do that I need to somehow pass the information (an id, or the headline itself) on to the form, so I can there read the proper article and other info from the database. It seems like a very simple task, but I've come to notice it seems like an impossible task. I could of course put the whole form inside a javascript function and then pass on the headline as a parameter using this.innerHTML to the function and then read it from a variable, but then I'd have to generate all the html using javascript, or php, but I think there must be a simpler way to do this.

I've tried using a hidden input tag and others like span and div elements and then pass the headline there as the input elements value using onclick="document.getElementByID("elementsname").value=this.innerHTML;" and onclick="document.getElementsByName("elementname")[0].setAttribute("value/name", this.innerHTML);". Something like this would be so simple, but for some reason unknown to me these methods don't work. Either the info doesn't get there, or it's not further readable from the elements by javascript.

For example I can pass on the info using input element when setting it to type="text" and it shows up on the page as a text field, but it's not readable from there for some reason and it doesn't even appear on the code when checking the source code from the browser. Why is this? For that reason I can't get the info passed to my SQL query, so I could read the corresponding news article in to a textarea from database.

So, is there a way to somehow make that idea to work, or should I forget it and use other methods? How is this usually done anyway by web developers when they want to open something for editing/updating from database?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is usually going to be accomplished using ajax and a separate template view for the form which is populated dynamically server side.

You will have your page of news articles. When one is clicked, it will make an ajax request to your server with an identifier for the article. The server will compose a page containing a WYSIWYG editor pre-filled with the information from the article inside of a set of input elements along with a save or cancel action.

The response from the server with this template page will come in the success callback in your page of news articles which will then popup a modal type of element containing the server side produced view.

Upon completing changes if the view is saved an update is called to the relevant news article on the page, as well as posting the changes to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I didn't know ajax is used for this type of a job as I've always associated ajax with only realtime updating of info on webpages like sports livescore updates and such. However I'd like to do this without using ajax and do the coding myself as I need to learn how to do everything myself. Besides this is a very small scale thing, so using ajax I think would be unnecessary for my project. I also want to be able to easily and completely control the look of my forms, UI and everything. I have not yet learned ajax properly either and that will still have to wait a while.

Comment: @Mr.Asker - AJAX is not as scary as it sounds :) It refers to using javascript to sort of mimic a user navigating to one of your pages. Except instead of them having to go there, all they have to do is ajax there. This is done with an "xhr" request. The Mozilla Developer's Network has a wealth of knowledge if you are just learning javascript or client side web technologies. **[XML Http Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)** has an explanation with examples of how to make an ajax request. The document is large, but it should cover a lot of basics for you.

Comment: Yes I know. I've gone through the basics of ajax quickly, but have not yet properly learned it and used it and I will do that a bit later. However I want to do this without it at this time. :)

I just need to know how to pass the id, or the headline itself when clicking the headline to my form so I can get my SQL query to get the corresponding article from the database.

Comment: I have further tracked why the attribute manipulating didn't work and it doesn't make any sense at all to me.

This is the php code for generating the headline links, which are then clicked:

echo $row["Postdate"] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"#\" class=\"header\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('popup').style.marginLeft=0+'px'; document.getElementById('header_list').style.opacity=0; document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].setAttribute("data-headline", this.innerHTML);\">" . $row["Header"] . "</a><br/>";

Comment: Now if the setAttribute manipulation is put there, or elsewhere inside a function and then the function call is put here instead, it won't work, but whenever I put that same piece of code elsewhere (not here, or inside a javascript function) it works just fine. How can this be? It doesn't make any sense to me and seems completely illogical. These are the kind of illogical behaviours I don't understand in HTML DOM and element attributes and makes coding unnecessarily difficult sometimes.

Comment: I CAN pass the needed info to an element's innerHTML, but then it somehow goes to some unknown dataspace somewhere where it can't be read from any further and thus results in a NULL, or unspecified, or whatever value instead of what was put there. It won't appear in the webpage's generated source code either and yet it is there printed on the page, but just cannot be grabbed from the element by any means, at least to my knowledge. Does anyone know why? This little "feature" makes passing data inside a webpage insanely difficult instead of being very easy and simple.